# Qjackctl Play Button doesn't work with external MIDI device

Tags: jack, midi

I use Ubuntu Studio 22.04.3 LTS.

Also, I use Jack Audio Connection Kit.

I have an Alesis Q88 MKII MIDI keyboard controller and it works so fine with my computer. But...

This device has transport control buttons (Stop, Play and Record) I cannot to get "connect" with Jack MIDI Transport System.

It supposed those controls could command the Qjackctl transport buttons, but it is not the case.

When I use Gmidimonitor, I can see the following MIDI Messages from the Alesis device:

STOP BUTTON:
[image]

PLAY BUTTON:
[image]

RECORD BUTTON:
[image]

Does somebody know how to get that values work with Jack MIDI Transport?